# Google Sheets: SUM multiple numbers in same CELL based on Word

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to calculate **SUM** how many items sold, the sold items are encased in brackets, example: **1st Product Title [ 1 ]** (for this product **1st Product Title** the customer buy only **1 item** so how can SUM quantity sold for each product even if there are many products recorded in the same CELL:

Sheet Link (you can edit it to help me):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xoNPfIfrVv7jF8W3Pa67Iu9oJRz2NOncW7oLQ94mWQ4

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this formula in cell `B2`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({ArrayFormula( 
                   {REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(flatten(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(A3:A,",")))),"where Col1 <>''"),"[^\[]+"), 
                    REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(flatten(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(A3:A,",")))),"where Col1 <>''"),"\[(\d+)")*1}) 
                }, "select sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' "))
```

[image]

Functions used:
+ [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
+ [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
+ [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
+ [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
+ `flatten` *Undocumented*
+ [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
+ [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos, thank you so much for your answer, I copy-paste your formula in B2 cell but it's not working? you can check the Sheet and see I got #REF! error

Comment: That is because you have still **not cleared cells `C2` and `D2` and the formula cannot be expanded**. Please clear those cells and the formula will work.

Comment: Yes, it's working well now, thank you so much bro for your help

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Enter following formula in B2 and Copy it from B2 to D5

```
=IF($A2="","",IFERROR(MID($A2,(FIND("[",$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2,1))+1),(FIND("]",$A2,FIND("[",$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2,1))+1)-1)-(FIND("[",$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2,1))+1)+1),0)*1)
```

[image]

**Edit:** As per your comment below, adding formula for Price Columns. Just replace "[" with "€", and reference to the top cells in the columns.

```
=IF($A3="","",IFERROR(MID($A3,(FIND("€",$A3,FIND(B$1,$A3,1))+1),(FIND("]",$A3,FIND("€",$A3,FIND(B$1,$A3,1))+1)-1)-(FIND("€",$A3,FIND(B$1,$A3,1))+1)+1),0)*1)
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214702/discussion-on-answer-by-naresh-bhople-google-sheets-sum-multiple-numbers-in-sam).